# Caret behavior inside contenteditable true and next to contenteditable false elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a **textarea that listens to URLs typed, pasted or dropped and converts them to links. These links are not editable and must be treated as blocks. Delete and backspace must delete them.** Finally, it would be nice if they show full selection when the caret is moved through them.

Problems: after spending too much time and trying some of the suggested solutions found here on stackoverflow (Tim Down), I still couldn't get it to work correctly. I'm finding it very hard to have the caret in the correct place all the time and after pasting a link and the automatic conversion is done, the selection is locked and no input can be done. I tried to insert and keep a zero width character before and after each link but then other selection problems started to occurr.

Can someone please have a look at the following fiddle which represents a simplified version focusing the problem and point me to the right direction **for the correct keyboard navigation through these non-editable links inside a contenteditable div**?

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/mrcukgss/2/)

```
$("#customtextarea").on("input propertychange drop paste", function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), savedSelection = saveSelection($this.get(0));
    var parsedHtml = getParsedHtml($this.html()); // This gets the innerhtml with the urls turned to links
    $this.html(parsedHtml).focus();
    restoreSelection($this.get(0), savedSelection);
});
```

---

**EDIT**: I've taken the approach suggested by XuoriG and I'm still facing more or less the same issues as before: caret gets 'stuck' after the link and the links can't be deleted. Also keyboard navigation (left, right) is not working.

[New jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/qwxvgLc4/9/)

Answer (score 0):

When using `$this.html` you're replacing the entire DOM and losing your selection.

The way I was able to do this is by creating and removing DOM nodes on the fly on every key up. I can't post code for you right now but basically you go through every node on key up and create a new anchor tag with the content matched by your url regex and remove that from text node. Repeat until you dont have any more matches in the node. You'll be able to save and restore the selection this way.

The hard part after is being able to append to an existing url. The way I did it is by detecting if a text node is right next to an anchor tag, and if the `anchor text + the text node` matches an url too you append the text node to the anchor tag and remove the text node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your suggested, but I'm still at the same point. I've updated the question with another fiddle. Can you please have a look?